# How to debug websockets in tomcat 9 with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, websocket

Java 10, Tomcat 9.0.1, Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0), Build id: 20181214-0600

Breakpoints in @ServerEndpoint ignored.

Long time servlet developer with experience debugging servlets running on a remote Tomcat server tasked with implementing a web socket application.  Web sockets working as they should but I have a business logic error I need to debug.  When I attach the Eclipse debugger to Tomcat I can debug my servlets just fine however execution never stops at the breakpoints in my @ServerEndpoint.  What do I need to do to be able to pause at the breakpoints in the @OnMessage method?

Thanks,
Jim

@ServerEndpoint("/XXXXXWebSocketEndPoint")
public class TradesWebSocketEndPoint
{
    ....
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String aMessage, Session aSession)
    {
        CODE TO DEBUG
    }
    ...
}

Expected results:  execution pauses at breakpoint.
Actual results:  execution does NOT pause at breakpoint.

Comment: Are you setting the breakpoint before attaching?

Comment: Yes.  I set all my breakpoints than attach to the running Tomcat.

Comment: Try it in the other order, setting them after you've connected.

Comment: That solved it.  I don't know why.  I can debug regular servlets the other way just fine.